# Double quotes show up as &quot; in preview

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

And the ampersand in this title shows up as `&amp;` in the preview. The symbols just need to be decoded again (or not encoded at all, yet) for the preview title. There are no problems with this previewing the question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this, it's fixed for the next release.